# How do I switch between different versions of Julia (specifically between v0.3 and v0.4 on Ubuntu)?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, julia

I am working on some projects using Julia v0.3. However, I'd like to test my code in both v0.3 and v0.4 (since some of the people that are going to be using it are already using v0.4). I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 and have installed Julia using apt-get. I know v0.4 is available through the PPA julianightlies, but if I add this, v0.3 is replaced. Is there a way I can install and quickly switch between both versions for testing purposes?

Comment: Install v0.3 using binaries from the site, install 0.4 from GitHub source in a different location, set your bash preferences so that `julia4` and `julia3` invoke the separate versions.

Comment: Use the `Generic Linux Binaries`. They come with an executable which you can alias or symlink something to.

Comment: @AlexA. I'm feeling a little sheepish that I didn't think about getting 0.4 direct from GitHub instead of the PPA.

Comment: @harts12: It happens. :) If the approach I mentioned in my comment ends up working for you I'll post it as an answer.

Comment: @AlexA.: Go for it. I kept the v0.3 install from apt-get, and then followed your suggestion for v0.4, adding a `julia4` sym link to the compiled executable from GitHub in /usr/local/bin. I just left v0.3 as `julia`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can install different versions of Julia in different locations and set separate symlinks.

For example, you could download the v0.3 Linux binaries and install them to one location, then clone the GitHub source for v0.4 and install that in another location. Then set symlinks such as `julia3` for v0.3 and `julia4` for v0.4.

Run your code like:

```
$ julia3 somefile.jl
$ julia4 somefile.jl
```

Answer (score 1):

Install by compiling and then change your she-bang in the start of the file as

`#!/path_to/julia3`

or

`#!/path_to/julia4`

That will do the trick