# Installing Julia v0.5 on Ubuntu 16.04 while v0.6 is installed

Tags: installation, julia

I use v0.6, but certain packages do not function with v0.6 (such as Interact.jl). How can I install v0.5? I am running Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30785333/how-do-i-switch-between-different-versions-of-julia-specifically-between-v0-3-a

Comment: @Reza_Afzalan Thanks for the reply! I am pretty inexperienced with Ubuntu, do you know of a resource that would explain how to follow the steps mentioned in the answers you linked to?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firstly, you should **really** read the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30785333/how-do-i-switch-between-different-versions-of-julia-specifically-between-v0-3-a) that Reza Afzalan linked. It gives you everything you need to know about how to install. If you prefer a list:

1. Go to the Julia [download page](http://julialang.org/downloads/).
2. Download the Generic Linux Binary for your OS (probably 64-bit for Ubuntu 16).
3. Install it.
4. Find where the installed Julia binary executables are stored on your machine.
5. [Symlink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1951742/how-to-symlink-a-file-in-linux) Julia v0.5 and Julia v0.6 to different aliases, e.g. `julia5` and `julia6`. You can store the symlinks in a directory like `/usr/local/bin`.
6. Open `julia5`.
7. Start downloading your packages with `Pkg.add`.

Answer (score 11):

First we have to download the latest Julia version from https://julialang.org/downloads/

I used the “Generic Linux Binaries for x86” version. The choice between x86 and ARM depends on the processor of your machine. Also choose between 32 bit and 64 bit versions based on the operating system and processor you have on your machine.

After download, you will get a compressed tar.gz archive having name similar to “julia-0.6.2-linux-x86_64.tar.gz”. As the “julia-0.6.2-linux-x86_64.tar.gz” name suggests that I downloaded the Julia version 0.6.2 which is latest at the time of writing this.

The names may differ. Adapt the names accordingly.

Remember these are binaries, these don't need to be installed as they can be directly used from the directory they are extracted.

I am assuming that the downloaded file is in your ~/Downloads directory of Ubuntu.

Open the terminal and navigate to the directory where the downloaded tar.gz file is stored, in present case the Downloads directory.

The terminal when just opened will show:

```
x@xpc:~$
```

where `x` should be replaced by your username and `xpc` should be replaced by your computer name.

Navigate to the Downloads directory using `cd Downloads` and then press Enter to get following terminal:

```
x@xpc:~/Downloads $
```

Extract the tar.gz file using the command

```
tar -zxvf julia-0.6.2-linux-x86_64.tar.gz
```

Now a directory with extracted contents will be generated in the same parent directory as of the compressed archive with a name similar to `julia-xxxxxxxxxx` where `xxxxxxxxxx` may be a combination of alphabets and numerals.

This is the final directory you need to run the latest Julia version, no installation is needed.

To run Julia, you can directly run using the julia file in location `julia-xxxxxxxxxx/bin/julia` as discussed below.

Navigate to the bin directory in the extracted directory using

```
cd /Downloads/julia-xxxxxxxxxx/bin
```

The terminal will now be like:

```
x@xpc:~/Downloads/julia-xxxxxxxxxx/bin $
```

Now run the command `./julia` to run julia on the terminal as shown below.

The terminal will now change to julia as presented below. I know the representation is little different here as this is all I can manage to copy from the terminal to present it to you.

julia>
But the problem is that I have to navigate to the directory every time to run Julia.

Many people have discussed on the internet about defining the path and alias through very complex procedures and as I am not a hardcore computer geek, it was really difficult for me to understand.

I came to know about making a soft link.

So I decided to make a soft link to the Julia to run it directly from anywhere with a short command without navigating to the directory containing it.

I always try to do things neatly, so I decided to keep the extracted directory named `julia-xxxxxxxxxx` in the /opt directory of my system as most of my important programs reside in that.

You need root permissions to copy a file into the /opt directory, so I used the command `sudo su` and then provided password to get the super user privileges:

```
x@xpc:~$ sudo su
[sudo] password for x:
root@xpc:/home/x#
```

Now navigate to the directory presently containing the extracted directory:

```
root@xpc:/home/x# cd /Downloads/
root@xpc:/home/x/Downloads#
```

Copy the directory using:

```
root@xpc:/home/x/Downloads# cp -r julia-xxxxxxxxxx /opt
```

After the directory is copied to the destination, now we will make the soft link in a directory which is in the system path so that the soft-link can be called from any location to run Julia.

To find out the directories in the system PATH use `echo $PATH`, you will get a list of paths of directories separated by colon(`:`) such as `/usr/local/bin`. You can use any of them. I used `/usr/local/bin` for the soft link.

Navigate to the chosen folder.

```
root@xpc:/home/x# cd /usr/local/bin
```

The terminal will become

```
root@xpc:/home/x/usr/local/bin#
```

Create the soft link using

```
root@xpc:/home/x/usr/local/bin# sudo ln -s /opt/julia-xxxxxxxxxx/bin/julia julia
```

Now return to the normal user terminal using the keyboard combination Ctrl+D at the empty terminal `root@xpc:/home/x/usr/local/bin#`.

The terminal prompt will become:

```
x@xpc:~$
```

Type the newly made soft link i.e. julia in the terminal as shown below

```
x@xpc:~$ julia
This is where the magic happens and you get this:

julia>
```

The instructions can be used for any version of Julia in Ubuntu.

[Source](https://drsonusharma.com/install-julia-linux/)

Answer (score 1):

It's very easy, here's how to install it on Linux in 8 steps:

1- go to [Julia downloads page](https://julialang.org/downloads/)

2- Choose you version (32bit or 64bit) from **Generic Linux Binaries**, and then download it.

3- extract .tar.gz file in home or any place you would like to install Julia on it.

4- run >  `gksudo gedit /etc/environment` on your terminal to setup envirnment path.

5- edit file `:/Path_To_extracted_File/bin` in my case it was like this:
"`:/home/okasha/julia-d386e40c17/bin`"

6- Save edits and close the file.

7- **Restart** your machine.

8- Open your terminal again and run > `julia -version`
you shoud get  "`julia version 0.6.2`" for Example according to your installed julia version.

Run > `julia` to open julia session.

[Reference](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3RXtVG9kvEQ)

Answer (score -3):

Just type this

```
sudo apt install julia
```